# Custom Lint Rule: how to handle fix button click

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I followed [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) tutorial and it worked perfect for me. Now I want to add fix issue functionality. I am using Eclipse.

In **Lint Warnings** view we have **Fix** button, can I handle it?

For example when we have hard coded string (*android:text="Test"*) in **TextView** when you click **CTRL + 1**, help pop up opens with possibility to **Extract String**. What I am trying to do is to add extract hard coded dp values functionality.

Also it would be great if you could point me where I could find source code of already implemented lint issues.

Thank You.

Comment: so basically you'd like these to be moved to dimens.xml and referenced, correct?

Comment: Yes android:layout_height="100dp" -> ctrl+1 -> extract to dimens

Comment: Not sure if you want this feature or just want to write it by yourself, but if the former, maybe just fill feature request at http://b.android.com/ against Tools

Answer (score 3):

**Lint checks can be written standalone:**

- Writing a Lint check: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check
- Lint checks source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks

**Lint fixes are part of the ADT pluggin:** http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

> Lint is integrated with ADT 16 and later. The integration offers a few features above the command line version of lint:
>
> - **Automatic fixes for many warnings**
> - Lint gets run automatically on various editing operations
> - Ability to suppress types of errors as well as specific instances of an error
> - Ability to configure issue severities
> - Jump directly to the problem source from the lint view

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a plugin for your Custom lint check in **IntelliJ Idea Community** **edition**, downloaded from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/, and follow the tutorial at http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html.

After then you will come to know that to handle light bulb for the fix of your custom Lint warning you have to extend the **IntentionAction** class particularly.

And then search for deploying the plugin in the tutorial and finally you will come to know to put the jar of the plugin thus created in the Android Studio/Contents/plugins folder.

Comment: for already implemented lint issues check out this https://github.com/bignerdranch/linette/tree/master/lint/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/linette